# Guardar objetos en instancia Vue con Vue-Cli

Tags: ajax, vue.js

Estoy tratando de emplear un modelo con Vue-cli. En este modelo tengo clases para crear diversos objetos.

En el `main.ts`, el archivo TypeScript encargado de manejar toda la aplicación, he añadido esta ruta a la cabecera:

`import './model/Repository'`;

Que importa el archivo Repository (en TypeScript) y que contiene esto:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
// import baseURL from "../config.ts.php";

class Repository{

    public url:string;
    
    constructor(url:string){  // = baseURL + 'www/php/'
        this.url = url;
    }

    peticionAjax(urlRequested:string , callback:any){ // a lot of functions for diverse ajax requests

        axios.get(this.url + urlRequested)
            .then((response:any) => {
                let datos = response.data;
                callback(datos);

            })
            .catch(function (error:any) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
                // console.log("There's a problem with axios");
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
                // console.log('Axios request executed');
            });


    }

    
}
```

El tema es que en el `main.ts` quisiera crear un objeto de la clase Repository para poder pasársela a la instancia Vue principal y así poder hacer uso del objeto en todo momento, ya que este objeto es el encargado de realizar todas las peticiones Ajax. Ejemplifico como debería quedar:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import './model/Repository';


let repo:Repository = new Repository(); // no reconoce Repository


Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let myVue = new Vue({
  data:"hola",
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");


myVue.$data = repo; // le paso el objeto
```

El tema es que no reconoce la clase Repository y por tanto no puedo instanciar el objeto, seguramente no sea la forma de emplear un modelo con Vue-cli. Pero no encuentro información clara al respecto en la documentación oficial.

¿Dónde estoy haciéndolo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer la clase exportable, de otro modo no se podrá importar:

```
export class Repository {
}
```

Y para importarla deberás importar la clase del path donde tengas la clase:

```
import Repository from './model/Repository';
```